# How many extrema for the function $f(x)=3x^4-4x^3+6x^2+ax+b$

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

For all $a,b\in R$ the function $f(x)=3x^4-4x^3+6x^2+ax+b$ has :
$(A)$no extrema
$(B)$exactly one extremum
(C)exactly two extrema
(D)three extrema

---

$f(x)=3x^4-4x^3+6x^2+ax+b\Rightarrow f'(x)=12x^3-12x^2+12x+a$
For extremum,$f'(x)=12x^3-12x^2+12x+a=0$

What should i do now to determine the number of extrema? It appears that there are 3 extrema,because $f'(x)=0$ is a cubic equation. But in the answer in the book,exactly one extremum is the answer. Can someone please explain me why is it so?

Comment: Maybe the second dericative is strictly positive. Check this. Since it is of second order, it should be easy. Between extrema there has to be a sign change in the second derivative. If there is none, you can argue using this and the fact that $f(x)\to \infty$ for both $x\to\infty$ *and* $x\to -\infty$.

Comment: @Antitheos,if there is no sign change in the second derivative,why is no extremum option not correct.Why we ruled out that option.My this concept is weak sir.That's why i am asking.

Comment: @NaN Sorry, I deleted my earlier comment.

Comment: @diya $f'(x) = 0$ has at least one real solution, so there is an extremum. You can show that using Descartes' Rule of Signs and considering two cases, where $a$ is non-negative and $a$ is negative (http://www.purplemath.com/modules/drofsign.htm). Alternatively, the easier approach proposed by Antitheos of examining the function's behaviour at either "end" of the x-axis can be used.

Comment: @diya When $f(x)\to\infty$ for both $x\to\infty$ and $x\to -\infty$ (together with $f$ being continuous) implies that there has to be at least one minimum. An other argument can be made: $f$ has an odd degree (3), so it has at last one root with sign change. This means there has to be at least one extremum.

Answer (score 3):

The second derivative of the function is given by

$f''(x)=12(3x^2-2x+1)$

Which is positive for all x∈R, regardless of $a,b$ meaning there are no inflection points, and that there is at most one minimum to $f(x)$.
 Also: $f'(-\infty)<0$ and $f'(\infty)>0$. Meaning there is atleast one minimum to the function.

From this you can conclude the function has one extremum.

Comment: You'll need a bit more to conclude that it has exactly one extremum. It's still possible there are no extrema.

Comment: @Deepak: a third degree polynomial always has a real root, so your objection can be rejected. The discriminant of the second derivative of our function is negative, hence there is exactly one stationary point. We do not need anything else.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Not an objection. Just advice to complete the proof (at the time I made the comment no mention was made of the first derivative at all). If the answer had been prefaced with "hint",I would've assumed something was being left for the asker to work out. But failing that, it needs to be a concise but complete solution. Yes every cubic has either one or three real roots but that at least has to be stated for completeness. In any case, the answer has now been edited and is acceptable.